# Insert a comment through Office Javascript API

Tags: javascript, ms-office

Is there a way to insert a comment on the current selection using the MS Office Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct 'add comment" method in the Office JavaScript API. However you can use setSelectedDataAsync with coercion type "OOXML". You can pass in an blob of OOXML (Office markup) that will be understood by Word and can insert comments that way. This blog post gives some information on inserting data with coercion type OOXML: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/10/26/inserting-images-with-apps-for-office.aspx

Comment: We thought about this but the comments are stored in a separate part of the document and linked to the actual text via a reference so I'm not sure how this could work. e.g. the ooxml in the document would be <w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>going to</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/> and then there would be a section in the comment.xml with the text of the comment

Comment: Any other ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should work using OOXML. When writing WordOpenXML to a document the XML you provide is in the ODC "flat package" file format, which means you're passing in a complete Word document. All the individual XML "parts" are written out into single string. So you can provide not only document.xml content but other content, as well. Granted, this can be quite complex - but it is possible.

This article provides some basic information on the OOXML format (what it must contain, how it's constructed, etc.): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423225.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you feel more comfortable constructing the OOXML using the Open XML SDK it's possible to convert the "zip package" to the "flat file" using the tool published by Eric White: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format.aspx